# Is it possible to request block producers to delete a file through IPFS?

Tags: storage

I understand that files are stored using IPFS protocol, but that only creates a content hash and the file is stored by the BPs.

Is there a way to request BPs to permanently delete a file then?

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship with EOS and IPFS, they're completely separate. 
The EOS Storage project proposes using the IPFS protocol for storing files. 
The idea is that you stake tokens for the nodes to store the file, should you unstake the file they'll likely stop hosting the file in order to make room for other files they'd get paid to host.

However, there's no guarantee other machines will continue storing the IPFS file, whether it's a node, the FBI or your mums laptop.

An **analogy** is like torrents on PirateBay, you're paying for the BP's to seed a TV show. If you decide to stop paying them to seed the file that doesn't change everyone else seeding the file.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated storage for EOS system is coming later this year.  In the meantime, developers have to use their own external storage (which can include IPFS) and manage how they want.